# Email Templates not looking fine in Android when I switch to Landscape mode

Tags: android, ios, email, email-templates

The email is confidential so I can't share much code ... Well I have created email template which works fine in browser mails (yahoo, outlook and gmail), Iphone (gmail and yahoo clients) and Android (yahoo client). The problem is **ONLY** with Android **gmail** client when I switch to **landscape** mode, else every where it is working PERFECTLY fine.

Is there any problem with landscape mode in Android ... why is it behaving weird ?

**Note:** I am using Nexux 5 ...

**Edit:**

**Partriat mode:**

[image]

**Landscape mode:**

[image]

Comment: you need to handle this in your html page

Answer (score 0):

Give max-width to a extending TD, gmail app I'll try to make 100% width for TDs having no width and adjust. If you are placing image inside TD set max-width for that also.